# Assertion is still failing, even though I removed all assertion statements

Tags: visual-c++

I am creating a small lab program for school, I got it to work and then I wrote in some assertions. One of the assertions failed and now, no matter what I do, I can not get the assertion to stop failing.

I've tried commenting out any all assertion statements, as well as not longer including cassert

Here is the assert statement that the compiler keeps saying has failed, even though I completely removed it from my code and recompiled the program.

EDIT- I fixed the time zone on my PC (windows changed it somehow) and restarted my program. Program is compiling and running normally now.

assert(isFullStack());

Comment: If you completely removed the assert from your program and have recompiled then it is no longer in your program therefore can't be the cause of your assert. You need to provide the actual output that your program is creating including the assert message. Also how are you running this program? Are you using a debugger and the program is stopping at an assert breakpoint and showing you the exact statement where it is asserting? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-call-stack-window?view=vs-2019

Comment: I can't figure out how to copy the output from the window. But after saving my project, I realized the time zone on my PC was wrong. I corrected the time zone and now my programs works normally. I also restarted my PC, so that might have solved my issue as well.

Comment: I suggest you delete this post. it has little chance of helping anyone in the future as there is insufficient detail in the question and the answer is vague and unhelpful.

Comment: Is it going to cause any issues if I leave it up?

Comment: The main issue for you will be if people decide to start downvoting the question and the answer which affects your rep. It clutters up the questions and answers. On the other hand it does give other people badge progress as they vote to close it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the time zone on my PC (windows changed it somehow) and restarted my program. Program is compiling and running normally now.